# Use a node package client side to save html to docx

Tags: node.js

I am struggling with this rather simple/straightforward task of converting any given html to docx file client side.

I tried using packages such as `docx`, `html-doc-js`, `html-pdf` etc but all of them fail and I am not sure what to do to make this work.

The project that I am working on is Wordpress based and I have little ideas how to use the server-side packages. I am new at dealing with server side functionalities so any help is appreciated.

Errors that I got:

> Cannot resolve module 'fs'
>
> fs.readfilesync is not a function
>
> Cannot resolve module 'child_process'
>
> Cannot find module 'fs'

Comment: WordPress....your looking at the completely wrong technology here, search for PHP packages that will convert HTML to Word.

Comment: I agree. The thing is that we are trying to move away from WP dependencies and we recently upgraded our entire app to ReactJS. WP is only being used for user related features (login, signup etc), hence I was trying to find a JS solution for this.

Comment: In that case why not create a microservice and have your WP site call out to that?

Comment: That is what I will do. There are models and controllers setup for fetching app related data, docx conversion will just be another one that won't have wp dependencies.